# Unable to read directories or files from a sd card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am new to android development and I have tried to read a directory from my sd card but didn't got succeeded. Below is the code which I wrote to achieve it

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();           
if(sdcard.exists()) {
    Log.d("Sd card", "Sd card exist");
    File[] file_names = sdcard.listFiles();
    for(File x : file_names) {
        Log.d("File Name",x.getName());
    }
}
```

Control passed the if condition and then I got an NullPointerException at "for each" loop line. Probably function sdcard.listFiles() is returning null. I have an Sd card with many folders and files. Actually I have to create a directory file object for directory "Attachments" which is available on my sd card. I also tried the following code to achieve the same.

```
File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +     File.separator + "Attachments");
```

and

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Attachments");
```

on both code when I called the function file.exists(), it returned false.

I have also checked whether sd card is mounted or not by the following code.

```
String sdCardAvail = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
 if(sdCardAvail.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        Log.d("Card status", "Sd card Available");
```

The above code has printed "Sd card Available" at log cat.
So please help me out to know whether I am doing it correct or missing any thing.

Thanks....

Comment: "I have tried to read a directory from my sd card" -- [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is usually not [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). Beyond that, what version of Android are you running on? Do you have either the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions properly in your manifest?

Comment: `File[] file_names = sdcard.listFiles();`. So `file_names` can be null. Add a statement `if ( file_names==null) do not continue..`

Comment: Yes I didn't mentioned the permission in the manifest file. Added it and its working now. Thanks CommonsWare greenapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must acquire the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`or`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` system permissions. For example:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

If you need to both read and write files, then you need to request only the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, because it implicitly requires read access as well.

Also See This [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). It Will solve all your future regarding **Storage** problems.

Comment: Yeah it works .... Added permissions in manifest file and its working now. Thanks a lot